# Proper protocol if no answers yet?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

What are the ways to get an unanswered question attention, other than it getting up-voted?  Is it proper to edit the question so it shows up with newest/unanswered again?  If this is frowned upon, what do people do to get their question "back on the radar"?

I am not talking about obscure unanswered questions. I'm thinking of genuine practical problems that a `stackoverflow` solution hasn't been found for yet, and others can likely help answer. Are tags and votes the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Proposing a bounty for that question will for sure get you a lot of attention.